# Run openface docker container on Heroku

Tags: docker, heroku

I'm trying to deploy https://hub.docker.com/r/bamos/openface/ image to Heroku, so I downloaded the code from https://github.com/cmusatyalab/openface and followed those steps https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime.

The push and release seems to be working, but when I try accessing the app url, I get this error why inspecting via `heroku logs --tail`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./demos/web/websocket-server.py", line 22, in <module>
import txaio
ImportError: No module named txaio
```

So I tried adding `txaio >= 2.10.0` to the `requirements.txt`, but nothing changed.

What else can I try? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Explain your steps better so one can point out where things may be going wrong

Comment: Those were my steps, the ones from the Heroku documentation. Should I copy them here?